# Reclaim Memory in Intellij Idea

Tags: memory-management, intellij-idea

I have an heap size of 1GB for my Intellij. I would prefer not to increase it further. I have noticed that the Memory Used by the IDE progressively increases after each run of an particularly heavy Junit Test case. After it hits the upper limit, I had to restart the IDE. Performing GC does not work.

Could this be related to my code? Or is there a way to reclaim memory in Intellij.

Edit: I have more information about it now. It seems that the memory is not reclaimed from the Junit thread, if the thread is interrupted (by pressing the red button to stop the test) or if it fails because of an exception. I will do more memory profiling and submit a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should not affect an IDE. If you are right, it looks like a bug, a memory leak. You should report it in Jetbrains.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not raise  an generic bug like that. Is there a way to profile intellij (other than the Jconsole, Jhat stuff.)

Comment: There is, check http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-192 (Memory Snapshot section).